# Retrieve reference to content type in preprocess

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a content type (let's name it Wheel for an example) that have a field referencing an other content type (which could be Car, Motorbike, Bicycle ...).
So a node named WheelMotorbikeBrand whould reference the content type Motorbike.
I would like to retrieve the value of this field in a preprocess with something like $node->get('field_wheel-type') but I'm not able to obtain a value.
How can I retrieve the value of my field ?

Answer (score 3):

You get a field value:

```
$value = $node->field_text->value;
```

If the field has a property `value` like fields for texts, numbers or booleans usually have.

A reference field has no `value` property, but one for `target_id`. So you get the id of the referenced entity with:

```
$target_id = $node->field_reference->target_id;
```

Or the referenced entity already loaded:

```
$referenced_node = $node->field_reference->entity;
```

Which you then can use to obtain a field value from the referenced node:

```
$value = $referenced_node->field_text->value;
```

---

The method `->getValue()`:

```
$values = $node->field_text->getValue();
```

gets an array of all properties and field items and so works also if you don't know the properties of a field or how many items it has.

Caveat: You don't find the property `entity` from the example above in this array, because it is computed and not stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
$value = $node->get('field_wheel-type')->getValue();
```

Comment: It's working indeed. What is the difference between ->getValue() and ->value ? I thought it was the same.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: ->value is a protected attribute.
->getValue() is a public method to get that protected attribute.